# make slideUp and slideDown work on bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want jQuery's `slideUp` and `slideDown` method to work smoothly on bootstrap's navbar. But as I tested it, when `slideUp` method was applied, the navbar only slid up only a little part of it, then disappeared immediately, the same went to `slideDown`, only in the opposite direction. Why did this happen and how to make the animation work smoothly?

The snippet is as follows.

```js
$('.slideUpBtn').click(function() {
  $('nav').slideUp("slow");
});
$('.slideDownBtn').click(function() {
  $('nav').slideDown("slow");
});
```

```css
.slideUpBtn {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.slideDownBtn {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>temp</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header"><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <button type="button" onclick="slideUp_event()" class="slideUpBtn">slideUp</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="slideDown_event()" class="slideDownBtn">slideDown</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.navbar` class has a `min-height` of `50px`. You should remove it.

```
.navbar{
  min-height:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsesvg4n/3/)

Comment: I debugged for days to try to solve the problem but to no avail. The solution is unbelievably simple, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This happened because the nav element has CSS property "min-height: 50px;"  from class navbar, and methods slideUp and slideDown increase and decrease the height property so when height go under min-height it will be ignored.

you can overwrite the min-height or change buttons function as the following:

```
 $('.slideUpBtn').click(function() {
   var minHeight = $('nav').css('min-height');
   $('nav').css('min-height',0);
   $('nav').slideUp("slow", function(){
            $('nav').css('min-height', minHeight);
    });
});
$('.slideDownBtn').click(function() {
     var minHeight = $('nav').css('min-height');
   $('nav').css('min-height',0);
  $('nav').slideDown("slow", function(){
            $('nav').css('min-height', minHeight);
    });
});
```